# Fotopro monopod tilt head — available in the USA?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, tripod-heads

When I was looking for a head for my new monopod, I came across the Fotopro RH-10, which besides be gorgeous is exactly what I want: ultra light weight with only tilt needed, arca-swiss plate.  (exactly? well, I'd like the plate to go the other way, but for that low weight adding an adaptor is fine)

My order was refunded, though, because it was out of stock. It seems to be hard to find, and none are in the USA.  I found their catalog (image of page 30 below), but how can it be that nobody carries them?

**Is this company legit?**  Any good?  I wonder if they normally make re-branded items since some of the other heads look familiar.  If that's the case, where might I find a head Just Like This but called something else?  Or, does anybody know where to get one that Google doesn't?

[image: page 30]

Comment: I generally use the lens collar for switching between portrait and landscape. I use the tilt on my Manfrotto 234RC tilt head to tilt up and down. Of course the 234RC uses a Manfrotto 200PL-14 plate rather than an arca-swiss plate.

Answer (score 1):

I use a $10 generic Arca clamp with Manfrotto's 3232, since replaced by their 234 (without RC).  Loosen the Manfrotto mount screw to reorient the Arca clamp
for tilting either camera plate or lens collar plate.

Amazon has the L10 panning tilt monopod head for $89
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00R5NG08G](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00R5NG08G)

L10 clones on ebay from $55 (item 251627716584)
or iShoot IS-6440JZ, $50 without panning (item 131149964801)

Comment: Thanks. It helps to know what names are out there to search for. Everything suggested (iShoot, RRS) is several, ti, es the weight, though. At 150 grams nothing comes close without being major expensive.  Can that be right?

Answer (score 1):

Poking around the [FotoPro](http://www.fotopro.com/en/) site, I don't see this head listed, so perhaps it's out of production.

This head reminded me of the [Really Right Stuff MH-01](http://www.reallyrightstuff.com/Shop/Monopod-Heads/), which also provides a way for the clamp to twist in either direction on the head.